# How can i detect my datagridview when keydown?

Tags: vb.net

i have a codes for selecting right cell in datagridview when datagridview cell changed or press enter key

but codes running always when i press enter key

how can i do this only i'm in datagridview ?

```
Private KeyHandled As Boolean
  Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
      If FAT_TABLO.RowCount = 0 Then Exit Function

      Dim icolumn As Integer = FAT_TABLO.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
      Dim irow As Integer = FAT_TABLO.CurrentCell.RowIndex

      If keyData = Keys.Enter Then
          If icolumn = FAT_TABLO.Columns.Count - 1 Then
              FAT_TABLO.Rows.Add()
              FAT_TABLO.CurrentCell = FAT_TABLO(0, irow + 1)
          Else
              FAT_TABLO.CurrentCell = FAT_TABLO(icolumn + 1, irow)
          End If
          Return True
      Else
          Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
      End If
  End Function
```

Comment: So you want to be able to press enter in the dgv and have it move towards the end of the row, then when it reaches the end, go to a new row?

Comment: exactly i tried more codes 
only this code worked 
when i changed any datagrid column cell value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            'add new dgv
            Dim Dgv1 As New DGV
            With Dgv1
    
                .AllowUserToAddRows = False
    
                .Columns.Add("ColA", "A")
                .Columns.Add("ColB", "B")
                .Columns.Add("ColC", "C")
                .Rows.Add(5)
                .Dock = DockStyle.Top
            End With
            Me.Controls.Add(Dgv1)
        End Sub
    End Class
    
Class DGV
    Inherits DataGridView

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessDataGridViewKey(e As KeyEventArgs) As Boolean
        If e.KeyData = Keys.Enter And Me.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            With Me.CurrentCell
                If .ColumnIndex < Me.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    'Move to next cell
                    Me.CurrentCell = Me.Item(NextVisCol(.ColumnIndex + 1), .RowIndex)
                    Return True
                ElseIf .ColumnIndex = Me.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                    If .RowIndex = Me.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        'Add new row 
                        Me.Rows.Add()
                    End If
                    'Move to first cell in next row
                    If Me.Rows(.RowIndex).IsNewRow = False Then Me.CurrentCell = Me.Item(NextVisCol(0), .RowIndex + 1)
                    Return True
                End If
            End With
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessDataGridViewKey(e)
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Enter Then Return ProcessDataGridViewKey(New KeyEventArgs(Keys.Enter))
        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function

    Private Function NextVisCol(Optional start As Integer = 0) As Integer
        For i As Integer = start To Me.Columns.Count - 1
            If Me.Columns(i).Visible Then Return i
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Columns.Count - 1
            If Me.Columns(i).Visible Then Return i
        Next
        Throw New Exception("All columns are not visible")
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Hi it didnt work.  Ehem i pres Enter button cursor going under row

Comment: It works fine with me , start a new project and put that code then add the custom DGV to the form ,run and test

Comment: Hi again,i added an example

https://yadi.sk/d/65MCJarFunkIGg

Comment: You need to learn more about `Inheritance` , I edited my answer

Comment: thanks for advice , but i have a problem with example codes
in my project  get data from access mdb table then update or save new data

Comment: ` 
Dim sorgu = "SELECT " & SORGU_METIN & " from CARTH002 A  WHERE A.KAYITNO =9999999999 ORDER BY A.SNO "
        Dim cm2 As New OleDbCommand(sorgu, cn) 
        With f.FAT_TABLO
            Dim dt = New DataTable()
            myDA = New OleDbDataAdapter(cm2)
            Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(myDA)
            myDataSet = New DataSet()
            myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "CARTM001")
            .DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("CARTM001").DefaultView

        End With 
`

Comment: in your sugestion codes i must add new datagrid always i understand
but i have a datagrid in my form
and some columns are visible
i 'm adding an example project again

Comment: you are using an older version of VS i think 2010,and it seems if modify your project you'll not be able to open it until you make an upgrade,   as a quick help remove lines from `Dim Dgv1 As New DGV` to `Me.Controls.Add(Dgv1)` then from `Solution Explorer` select show hidden files or something like that , expand `Form1.vb` then look for `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()` and change it to `DGV()`   you'll find 2 lines have  `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()`

Comment: Another thing , i prefer to set `AllowUserToAddRows` = `False` to avoid extra errors especially when it linked to a database  ,the code above has the ability to add a new row programmatically

Comment: Thank you very much 
i did it but only one problem left 
some columns visible false so i get an error when select visible false columns

The current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell.

Comment: @acar6783 you welcome, i make some changes ,test it and tell me